# blur and unblur effect and hover effect css and javascript

Tags: javascript, hover, blur

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4T4C.png)

when I hover on the text I can not get the x and y from the background. so the circle is stopped and the movement is not smooth. I need to move the circle as I want and when hovering on the text, it will display.

here is the code

https://github.com/safaa-alnabhan/blur-effcet?fbclid=IwAR0VJoVaeJhttWDgOeueFm-63a36pU866l7u9kMkYodbp6slAM-3XRUdIBM

Comment: Please edit your question to post the relevant code here.  If you can reproduce it in a code snippet (the { } icon in the text box), that would be even better.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

make "content" parent of all much better.

OR

```
            d.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
            if(e.target && e.target.classList.contains("moveable") ){
              //moveable class of all elements
                  getCoOrdinates(e);
             }

         });
```

and then you need to take e of the "content" not the "text "

Comment: could you edit the code for me? I am not good at javascript so I don't know how to get the e of content